# Right way to convert levels of column in a dataframe to numeric values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column that contains levels "Excellent, Very Good, Good, Fair, Poor." I would like to average these values, and work with them in other ways, by assigning the value 5 to "Excellent", 4 to "Very Good", and so on.

My various attempts are confounded by the fact that the default assignment of numerical values seems to take the levels in alphabetical order, so that "Excellent" is 1, "Fair" is 2, and so on.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you reverse the ordering of the levels?

Comment: Otherwise something like abs(level - 6) should invert the value so that "Excellent" = 5, "Fair" = 4 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a named vector as lookup table:

```
options = c('Excellent' = 5, 'Very Good' = 4, 'Good' = 3, 'Fair' = 2, 'Poor' = 1)
df = data.frame(grade = sample(names(options), 100, replace = TRUE))
head(df)
      grade
1 Very Good
2      Good
3 Excellent
4 Very Good
5      Fair
6      Good

df = within(df, {
    grade_numeric = options[grade]
})
head(df)
      grade grade_numeric
1 Very Good             1
2      Good             3
3 Excellent             5
4 Very Good             1
5      Fair             4
6      Good             3
```

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, I had tried this -- BUT when I created my lookup table, I used options=c("Excellent"=5,...).  I clearly need to read up on the significance of the different quoting mechanisms!

Comment: Hmm, the quoting should not matter, `'` is not treated differently from `"`. You must have made another mistake.

Comment: That's what I thought. Very strange.  But now it seems to be working, though I did have to put "as.character" into the indexing -- so in your example it's grade_numeric=options[as.numeric(grade)] -- otherwise "Very Good" came out as "N/A" in my example. Something weird is happening because your code works fine for me.

Comment: You have to take care with indexing using `factor`'s, as in some circumstances they are translated to `1`, `2`, etc. This is a quite common source of problems, have a look at the `stringsAsFactors` arguments to `data.frame` and `read.csv` to prevent characters being interpreted as a `factor`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the root of the problem, I believe.  I have default.stringsAsFactors()==TRUE and I used read.csv() uncritically.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need it to be an ordered factor? If so, using `factor` maybe your best bet.

Sample data

```
column <- c("Excellent", "Very Good", "Good", "Fair", "Poor",
        "Good", "Fair", "Poor")


col.f <- factor(column,
            levels = c("Poor","Fair" , "Good" , "Very Good", "Excellent"),
            labels = c("Poor","Fair" , "Good" , "Very Good", "Excellent"),
            ordered = TRUE)

col.f
[1] Excellent Very Good Good      Fair      Poor      Good      Fair      Poor     
Levels: Poor < Fair < Good < Very Good < Excellent
```

Then you can call `as.numeric(col.f)` to get numeric values.

Comment: Can you calculate a mean of this right now? Otherwise it does not really answer the question as it does not transform to numeric values.

Comment: Why use an *ordered* factor?

Comment: Well, I thought that Likert data from "Poor" to "Excellent" is best represented by an ordered factor. Also, from `?factor` "Ordered factors differ from factors only in their class, but methods and the model-fitting functions treat the two classes quite differently."